# CRM 3.0 outlook laptop client and .net 2.0 on windows 8 64bit

Tags: .net, windows-8, dynamics-crm, outlook-addin, dynamics-crm-3

I'm trying to force an install of the Outlook Laptop client for CRM 3.0 on a Windows 8 machine.  I get so far but then it won't recognize that .Net 2 is installed.  I think because it wants it to be installed by User and as it's part of the .Net 3.5 Windows features it cannot find it in installed programs list.

I have tried to install .Net 2.0 separately, but it does not work whether I have the features turned off or on.  It fails if I try and install when .Net 3.5 features are turned off and using compatibility settings.  If turned on it tells me that it's already installed as part of operating system.  I have also turned off compatibility checking in Group policy.

Could the issue be because there is a .Net V4 folder in C:/ and registry entries for it?

Is there a way to stop windows installer searching for installed programs when running?

I managed to bypass these issues on Windows 7 but installing .Net 1.1 and 2.0 directly - I have installed .Net 1.1 directly and that worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer in a Dynamics community site. This solution worked on my Windows 8.1 64 bit:

The problem is this registry key (in 64-bit Windows 8):

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\policy\v2.0

For some reason the installer wants to open it in Read/Write mode and gets an Access Denied which makes the installer think .NET 2 is not there. In order to fix this I had to take  ownership of the key and set Full Control to my user.

The original post is below:

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/p/105669/213813.aspx

Comment: You are right kleopatra. I have edited my answer and put the solution into the answer.